Appending to a list inside a recursive function changes all the items? Towers of Hanoi
I'm trying to make a list of matrices using numpy to represent the minimum number of moves to solve the towers of Hanoi problem. My solution works when I print m after each move but when I try and append m to a list, the resulting list just contains the final matrix repeated over and over. Here's my code:
def set_up(total,start):
    global moves

    moves = 0
    m = np.empty((3,total+1))
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(total+1):
            m[i,j] = -1
    for i in range(total):
        m[start,i] = int(total-i-1)

    m_list = [m]
    return m,m_list

def move_disk(total,num,m,move_from,move_to,m_list):
    global moves
    temp =m[move_from,np.where(m[move_from]==-1)[0][0]-1]
    m[move_from,np.where(m[move_from]==-1)[0][0]-1]= -1
    m[move_to,np.where(m[move_to]==-1)[0][0]] = temp
    moves = moves + 1
    m_list.append(m)

def towers_algorithm(total,num,m,start,middle,final,m_list):

    if num == 0:
        return
    else:
        towers_algorithm(total,num-1,m,start,final,middle,m_list)
        move_disk(total,num,m,start,final,m_list)
        towers_algorithm(total,num-1,m,middle,start,final,m_list)

I've tried passing the list as a parameter and making m_list a global variable. Both gave the same result.

maybe you have to duplicate list before you use it new_list = list.copy() or even new_list = copy.deepcopy(list) because normal new_list = list doesn't duplicate it (but it copies reference to the same object in memory) and you may use exactly the same list many times (many references to the same object in memory) - and when you append to one list then you append to all other lists.

@furas
It shouldn't be the case, list is passed as reference (as it is a mutable object).
Can you share your full code to be able to reproduce it?

You only create one m array, and keep adding its reference to m_list. So it is not possible that you would see different matrices in m_list, as you only created one.

@AME I don't understand your comment.

@furas, sorry I did not read the whole message before I answered. We are saying the same :D

@AME sometimes I have the same problem - I don't read whole message or read too fast without checking details :)

Your set_up function creates one m matrix, and that is the only time such a matrix is created. The rest of the code mutates m and performs m_list.append(m). But this will append the same array reference multiple times to m_list, and so that m_list will just have duplicates. Realise that there is only one m array, so you cannot expect m_list to somehow reference multiple, distinct arrays.
To solve this, make sure you create a new array every time you append to m_list. You can achieve this in different ways, for instance like this:
m_list.append(m.copy())


You're an absolute lifesaver, thank you!

You append m to m_list, where m only means a reference to that one instance that you created and assigned. It means whenever m's value is changed, wherever you use the reference, it will point to the same object as well.
In order to solve the problem, you have to create a copy of the object at a certain point where you want to use its current value.
m_list.append(m.copy())

This will create a new instance with the same values.
